# How do I stop my dog (a dachshund) from eating plastic?

Tags: dogs, health, eating

My doggy, Twitter, is fond of eating plastic.  Because of that, most of the time his stomach is upset.  How can we prevent this?

Comment: Have health related issues like teeth/gum health and diet been ruled out by your veterinarian?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent my puppy from chewing on objects?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1772/how-can-i-prevent-my-puppy-from-chewing-on-objects). Also, [How to stop dog chewing things](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6209/how-to-stop-dog-chewing-things)

Comment: There are a bunch of other questions/answers that cover chewing. If none of them help your specific situation, please edit this question to include more details so we can give specific advice.