# How Can I Reward My Puppy for Chewing His Toys Instead of Everything Else When He's so Food-Motivated?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, chewing, teething

This question is admittedly similar to [this](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1772/how-can-i-prevent-my-puppy-from-chewing-on-objects) but with some differences that I wanted to see if folks had any more specific advice on.

I have a 13-week old likely Shepherd mix puppy who's definitely a chewer. To be expected! We play as much as possible and I think I do a good job of getting him exercise (before he's finally done with his vaccinations at least), so hopefully I'm doing everything I can there. Also since he's teething I'm buying him a bunch of toys that should hopefully help him get through that like Kongs and stuff.

Every time he chews on something he shouldn't, I say "no" and/or "drop it" and then give him a toy to actually chew on. When he plays with his toys on his own, I want to give him as much positive reinforcement as possible so he knows those are the right ones. "Problem" there is he's *insanely* food-motivated. (Which is mostly great!) But if I give him even a tiny treat he will forget entirely about the toy and stop playing with it altogether in hopes that he can do something for another piece of kibble.

Anything I'm missing here that I could try to help him know he's doing the right thing beyond saying "good boy," giving him the treat, and watching him forget what he was doing before entirely? Unfortunately/understandably he doesn't mimic behavior as quickly as when it's just verbal positive reinforcement.

Comment: Clicker training? http://www.akc.org/content/dog-training/articles/what-is-clicker-training-a-great-way-to-shape-your-dogs-behavior/

Comment: @Kai           I'll check it out more, thanks! Also super weird cause my pup's name was Kai as a baby from his foster parents.